# Not able to save ListView state/values

Tags: android, listview, save

I'm creating this ListView with the option to add new item through menu, but I already read all the codes/examples here in Stackoverflow and I was not able to adapt my code with them.

I tried to use the `onSaveInstanceState` but I was not able to start the application when I try to use in `onCreate`.

What is the best way to save this list with the new values when entered?

Code that I tried to use:

```
protect void onCreate(...)
{
     ...
     if (savedInstanceState.containKey(MYLISTKEY))
     {
          alllist = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(MYLISTKEY);
     } else {

     }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String MYLISTKEY = "myListItems";
    final Context context = this;
    private ListView mainListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;`
    private ArrayList<String> allList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putStringArrayList(MYLISTKEY, allList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the ListView resource.
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView); 

        // TODO: Populate explicitely your list
        // Create and populate a List of planet names.
        String[] listitems = new String[] { };  
        allList.addAll(Arrays.asList(listitems));
        // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, allList);

        // Add more planets. If you passed a String[] instead of a List<String> 
        // into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items. 
        // Otherwise an exception will occur.
        listAdapter.add( "Item A" );
        listAdapter.add( "Item B" );

        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Action Add Item to the listview
        case R.id.action_add:
            addListItem();
            return true;
            // Save list to SharedPreferences
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // Add new item list when choose "New Item" on menu
    private void addListItem() {
        // get prompt.xml view
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        // set prompt.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

        final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // get user input and set it to result
                // edit text
                listAdapter.add(userInput.getText().toString());

                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post logcat?

Comment: What do u mean by save listview state

Answer (score 0):

As your comment `// Save list to SharedPreferences` suggests you should save the data in the list to some kind of persistent storage and not rely on the savedInstanceState bundle.

See the Android dev docs note re. what to store in onSaveInstanceState:

> **Note:** Because onSaveInstanceState() is not guaranteed to be called, you should use it only to record the transient state of the
>   activity (the state of the UI)—you should never use it to store
>   persistent data. Instead, you should use onPause() to store persistent
>   data (such as data that should be saved to a database) when the user
>   leaves the activity.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html